# Regex Full Name Validation

Tags: regex, validation, nspredicate

Is there a well-defined and thorough example of a Regex string of which can validate a Full Name?

I expect the string to be able to validate a majority of names such as:

- Stack Overflow
- John P. Example
- Martin Luther King, Jr
- and a variety of foreign letters (if possible)

Comment: I tried `/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i` but it marks all names as invalid.

Comment: And which language / platform are you using. Not all regex implementations support the exact same syntax

Comment: Objective-C (iOS), specifically using NSPredicate.

Comment: Something like that would match any word, not just names. What you are asking isn't possible with just a regex, you need a name database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be done because there is no way to determine if a string of characters is a word or a name without a data set.  The best that you can do is match strings that **could be** names, then check those positive results against a data set for confirmation.

Comment: See also [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).